# Msal login redirect takes too long to initiate the redirect

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

So I am using `"azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.1"`, and here is my code

```
async function onLogin() {
  try {
    await msalInstance.loginRedirect({ scopes: [] });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

The problem is that when the function is called it takes about 4 seconds to start redirecting which is pretty bad in terms the of the user experience and makes the website seem unresponsive.